# Delete/Drop similar tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I have a database in SQL Server where there are many similar tables such as `dbo.Dos_150602_xyz`. I tried to delete only the tables with 1506 in them by typing:

```
drop table dbo.Dos_1506*;
```

But that didn't work. How else can I perform this?

Thanks.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393/drop-all-tables-whose-names-begin-with-a-certain-string) might be helpful.

Comment: @learningNew shared a useful link this will generate a script which will also help you to cross check your desire table to DROP it

Comment: The script will do all the work, just modify/add the conditions - 
`where Table_Name like '%1506%' and TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`

Answer (score 2):

Just to make things a bit easier for the OP.

Sample table creation script:
    
    `create table table_pattern_name_1 ( s1 varchar(20), n1 int );
    create table table_pattern_name_2 ( s1 varchar(20), n1 int );
    create table table_pattern_name_3 ( s1 varchar(20), n1 int );
    create table table_pattern_name_4 ( s1 varchar(20), n1 int );`

Table Drop script:
    
    `declare @cmd varchar(4000)
    declare cmds cursor for 
    select 'drop table [' + Table_Name + ']'
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where Table_Name like 'table_pattern_name_%'
    open cmds
    while 1=1
    begin
        fetch cmds into @cmd
        if @@fetch_status != 0 break
        print @cmd
        exec(@cmd)
    end
    close cmds;
    deallocate cmds`

SSMS Output:
    
    `drop table [table_pattern_name_1]
    drop table [table_pattern_name_2]
    drop table [table_pattern_name_3]
    drop table [table_pattern_name_4]`

Let me know if this works for your example.

Thanks,
Matt Jones
Microsoft SQL Server