# Dropping table based on other table's Name

Tags: sql

Currently, I am basically dropping table like
drop table
    scratch..TableName

If I have name of all the table in other separate table, then can I do perform to drop table by joining instead of copying and pasting name every time?

So I want to do something like this.. but I am no sure how to write this to SQL.  I do use 2008 version.
Table name matches from TableName table, then delete from scratch database.

Comment: Wanting to do this indicates you might be "doing sql" wrong. You don't usually go around creating/dropping tables with names determined at runtime. Having said that, you *can* do this with dynamic SQL. You need to build a string consisting of a bunch of `drop` statements and then execute it as SQL. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393/drop-all-tables-whose-names-begin-with-a-certain-string) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a cursor that loops through the rows of your table and dynamically creates and executes a drop statement for every table. Something like this should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @i_Current_Drop_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Drop_Table_Statements CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR 
    SELECT N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    FROM sys.tables t --Or replace this with your table that contains the tables to drop

OPEN Drop_Table_Statements
FETCH NEXT FROM Drop_Table_Statements INTO @i_Current_Drop_Statement

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @i_Current_Drop_Statement

    FETCH NEXT FROM Drop_Table_Statements INTO @i_Current_Drop_Statement
END

CLOSE Drop_Table_Statements
DEALLOCATE Drop_Table_Statements
```