# Oracle- creating dynamic function for deleting tables based on cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, dml

I'm trying to build a dynamic function in Oracle using a cursor for all the tables that need to be dropped and re-created again.  For example, I have the following example table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE All_tmp_DATA AS
(SELECT 'T_tmp_test1' As Table_NM, 'TEST1' As Process_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'T_tmp_test2' As Table_NM, 'TEST1' As Process_name FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'T_tmp_test3' As Table_NM, 'TEST1' As Process_name FROM DUAL)
```

The above tables starting with "T_tmp" represent all the tables in the database which needs to be dropped if their counts are >1 when starting the TEST1 process.  I really need a function to pass in the parameter Process_name where I can input "TEST1", and build a loop using a cursor by binding it to the Table_NM from All_tmp_DATA and inserting it into table_name in the following code:

```
BEGIN  
  SELECT count(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM user_tables
    WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
  IF l_cnt = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE my_table';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: [Drop all tables whose names begin with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393/drop-all-tables-whose-names-begin-with-a-certain-string)

Comment: I've never heard of Oracle 13 before. Are you sure that version number is correct? Also, `SELECT CREATE TABLE...` is not valid Oracle syntax. Please clarify the database system you're actually using.

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry about the typos. If you get rid of the SELECT in the first line, it should create the temp table.  And It's ORACLE TOAD version 13.  Thank you, Yen

Comment: TOAD is a SQL client and its version is essentially irrelevant to your question. What's more relevant is the version of Oracle you are using (check e.g. `select * from v$version`)

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, I'd suggest you not to use mixed case when naming Oracle objects.

---

Test case:

```
SQL> select * From all_tmp_data;

TABLE_NM    PROCE
----------- -----
T_tmp_test1 TEST1
T_tmp_test2 TEST1
T_tmp_test3 TEST1

SQL> create table "T_tmp_test1" as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> -- I don't have "T_tmp_test2"
SQL> create table "T_tmp_test3" as select * From emp;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select table_name From user_Tables where upper(table_name) like 'T_TMP%';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
T_tmp_test3
T_tmp_test1
```

Procedure which drops tables contained in `ALL_TMP_DATA`:

- as opposed to your code, I concatenated table name with `DROP`
- as you use table names with mixed case, you have to enclose their names into double quotes, **always** (did I say not do use that?)

As the final `select` shows, those tables don't exist any more.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_nm from all_tmp_data) loop
  5      select count(*) into l_cnt
  6      from user_tables
  7      where table_name = cur_r.table_nm;
  8
  9      if l_cnt > 0 then
 10         execute immediate ('drop table "' || cur_r.table_nm || '"');
 11      end if;
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select table_name From user_Tables where upper(table_name) like 'T_TMP%';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

As of the `process` column: I have no idea what is it used for so I did exactly that - didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exception handling to handle such scenario directly as follows:

```
DECLARE
    TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT ( TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -00942 );
BEGIN
    FOR CUR_R IN (
        SELECT TABLE_NM
          FROM ALL_TMP_DATA
    ) LOOP
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table "' || cur_r.table_nm || '"';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('"' || cur_r.table_nm || '" table dropped.');
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('"' || cur_r.table_nm || '" table does not exists');
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```